# Syntax of Ille: "numquam est ille miser cui facile est mori"

Tags: syntax, grammar-identification, seneca-iunior

What is the syntax of *ille* in the sentence: "numquam est ille miser cui facile est mori"? I get that *cui* is indirect object, but what is the function of the demonstrative pronoun *ille* in the sentence?

Comment: I added the "Seneca" tag, since this sentence seems to come from his works; feel free to revert if this is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, *ille* is the subject of the sentence: just generically "he", or "that man", or "that person" (since masculine gender is sort of a default in Latin), or even just "the one".

You can split this sentence in half to make translation easier. The first half, *numqvam est ille miser*, is a full sentence in and of itself: "that man is never miserable".

And who is "that man"? That's what the second half clarifies: *…cui facile est mori* "…for whom dying is easy". To make this a bit more idiomatic in English, I'd say "someone who can die easily is never miserable".